# iOS : check whether keyboard is being displayed or not when app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I want to get keyboardshow and dismiss(like keyboard being used in other apps) notifications while my app is in background.My app is active in background using locations manager.

I have tried springboard notifications as well but didnt get any success

Any idea or suggestion to get this implemented?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why do you need to check for keyboard show/hide notification?

Comment: What is your Use Case for knowing a keyboard is show for another app?

Comment: I want to track whether user interacts with the keyboard or not irrespective of the app.We need this data further in our algorithm.